# Access violation when trying to run a very simple program

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

> "Unhandled exception at 0x0F29F365 (msvcr120d.dll) in HW2_1_JM.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF."

This is my first post, and that is the error I consistently get when I attempt to run this program. I'm new to programming, so I'm sorry for my code quality.  When it's not throwing this error, it's simply pausing endlessly before the while. We think the error is with `int d` because when we tried to print both `n` and `d` we get the error again after printing `n`.

```
int main()
{
   int a[10];
   puts("Please input a value: \n");
   int n;
   scanf("%i", &n);
   printf("\n you chose: %i\n", n);
   puts("Please input a base value, between 1 and 11: \n");
   int d;
   scanf("%i", &d);

   while (!(n = -1));
   {
      int q = n;
      int k = 0;
      printf(q);
      while (q != 0);
      {
         a[k] = (q % d);
         q = q / d;
         printf(q);
         k++;
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
      {
         printf("Element [%d] = %d \n", j, a[j]);
      }
      puts("Please input a value: \n");
      scanf("%i", &n);
      printf("\n you chose: %i\n", n);
      puts("Please input a base value, between 1 and 11: \n");
      scanf("%i", &d);
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (!(n = -1));`. The single equal sign and semi-colon look suspicious.

Comment: Is this c or c++? change `printf(q)` to `printf("%d\n", q)`

Comment: oh, thank you! I forgot about that one. When I changed it to "==" the loop still does not initiate. It just stalls after accepting a value for "d." It does not throw up the error anymore, but I have to X out of the cmd prompt. @NickyC

Comment: *update* I changed the "printf(q);" to "printf("%d\n", q);" and saw no change. my debug window still says "Cannot find or open the PDB file" and it says it "The program ___ has exited with code -1073741510" @BarmakShemirani

Comment: This looks like all `C` to me.  Also, if someone entered `0` for `d`, your program will fail miserably.

Comment: You have fixed `printf` but that was one problem, see other answers and comments. The compiler should warn you about these errors. Visual Studio will give you a bunch of warning about `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, you can ignore those, or add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` on top of the file. But don't ignore the other warnings. Try to make it compile with zero warnings, that way the obvious errors are removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 10-item array, but try to read 11 elements (0 through 10). Change your loop to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {
     printf("Element [%d] = %d \n", j, a[j]);
  }
```

Also, this is wrong:

```
while (!(n = -1));
{
```

You're doing an assignment when you want to do a comparison. And you have a misplaced `;`. Your code should be

```
while (n != -1)
{
```

Comment: Wow, that's an excellent point. I thought I was compensating for the array size but I wasn't really. I updated the code with the recommended fixes and it works! Well... it has some logic errors, like my array is filled with some really long negative numbers, but this is progress. Thank you all for the rapid responses!

Comment: @JeremyMorgan Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer if any of them helped you.

Answer (score 1):

1. `while (!(n = -1));` You might remove the semicolon here, otherwise the following `{}` won't be a part of the while loop.
2. `while (!(n = -1));` `n = -1` is an assignment instead of a comparison, which will be always evaluated as `true`, you might want `n == -1`.
3. `for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)` You're getting out of the array's range, which should be [0; 10). I suppose you want `j < 10`.

There might be other problems. You should try to use debugger to find out the actual errors.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for printf is
    `int printf ( const char * format, ... );`
Your calling `printf(q)` where q is an `int`